# FlatList with onLongPress callback

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I have a Flatlist that I would like to empty when the user long presses it.

The problem is that surrounding the Flatlist with a TouchableOpacity prevents scrolling.

I also **cannot surround each item with a Touchable opacity** because it's a list with columns and an uneven number of items. This means that at the bottom of the list, there is a leftover area with no items rendered.

This leftover area should still react to the long press (as it is where most users will try to long press).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I tried surrounding a `FlatList` with `TouchableOpacity` and it works perfectly, it doesn't prevent scrolling

Comment: I am not sure how you did it then. TouchableOpacity blocking Flatlist scrolling is a fairly common issue. Most solutions recommend enclosing the items inside TouchableOpacity (which is not enough in my case).